# .htaccess mask host to subdomain (without iframes)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

is it possible with .htaccess to mask a redirect of host to subdomain.

So that **example.co.uk** is masked to **subdomain.test.co.uk**, but still appears in browser as **example.co.uk**

I have tried using

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.co\.uk [NC]       
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.test.co.uk/$1 [NC,L]
```

But that just the redirect host to subdomain.test.co.uk, which isn't what I want.

Tried using [r=301] as one of the params too.

I have very limited access to hosting and it doesn't allow add-on domains (currently using parked domains to get host in .htaccess). If there is another solution I'm all ears :)

**UPDATE**

Tried changing the .htaccess to :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

ProxyRequests On
ProxyPreserveHost On

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} simplysleeptime\.co\.uk
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://simplysleeptime.labithiotis.co.uk/$1 [NC,P]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} zurvivor\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://zurvivor.labithiotis.co.uk/$1 [NC,P]
```

but i can't edit the **httpd.conf** to enable **mod_proxy** as I don't have ***full*** access to godaddy hosting.

Comment: Use `P` flag instead of `L`. Which means you must enable **mod_proxy**. Also, you can use absolute path with `L` flag if main domain and subdomain are pointing to the same document root folder

Comment: @JustinIurman Added an update above and also didn't full understand what you meant by i can use an absolute path?